# Setting Apache's PATH environment to match users

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, environment-variables, path

Using PHP 5.3 as an Apache module with Apache 2, on OS X 10.7.

When I open Terminal and enter `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/imagemagick/bin
```

But when I run `getevn('PATH')` in PHP I get:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Which means most calls to `exec()` in PHP fail to find the commands/binaries I want. I've tried these two in `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnv PATH /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/imagemagick/bin

PassEnv PATH
```

Neither have any effect. How do I get PHP/Apache's PATH variable to mirror my users PATH variable? (Ideally in such a way that if mine ever changes Apache's doesn't need manually changing as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `user` (directive) to your logged in username. I wouldn't recommend doing that in a productive environment. However to fiddle things out, in a closed test environment you get what you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This is only on a development machine so that's fine.